# Ball valve that connects to fridge waterline hose

Tags: refrigerator, valve, ice-maker

Looking for a male to male ball valve that will connect to the fridge water line hose. The hose says it 1/4. I purchased a ball valve on the internet that was 1/4 male to male but was too big for the water line hose connection. Not sure how to purchase the correct size.

Comment: How about some pictures so we can see what you see.

Answer (score 6):

Refrigerator water/ice-maker lines are typically 1/4" tubing (poly or copper). The fittings usually found on these systems are 1/4" **compression**, which is designed to work with special compression nuts and ferrules which attach to the tubing and seal by squishing (compression) of the ferrule.

Your ball valve probably has 1/4" pipe thread (NPT) which is totally different but can be easily adapted to *compression thread* with a couple inexpensive adapters.

Note- it is common to also find hoses with braided stainless-steel jacket used for connection. These are also typically equipped with 1/4" compression thread, so they can be easily used on existing systems.